# What are the best practices to avoid XSS and SQL Injections attacks (platform agnostics)?

Tags: xss, sql-injection, security

I wish there was a do/don't list (such as input sanitation, etc.) which when respected, such attacks are nearly impossible to succeed.

Comment: OWASP has a Development Guide. You should really skim through it. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_Table_of_Contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the OWASP Top Ten Project: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Answer (score 1):

Aha, you'll be wanting the [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and the [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) from OWASP, then.